# Multiple commands for Mongo Docker image

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am attempting to script some setup for Mongo instances in a Docker compose file. I seems as if the second command never runs (which should initiate this container as a primary in a repl set). Here is my command:

```
docker run -d mongo /bin/bash -c "mongod --replSet \"test\"; mongo --eval \"rs.initiate({_id:'test',members:[{_id:0,host:'localhost:27017'}]})\""
```

When I then exec in to the container and do an rs.config, it says intiate has not been ran. So, how do I go about issuing multiple commands to the startup of a Mongo container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're starting the mongo daemon as the first command.

Are you sure this command returns ? It doesn't seem to finish executing before you "docker exec" in the container. That could be why the second command isn't executed.

Maybe try to put the command in "background" with "&"

```
docker run -d mongo /bin/bash -c "mongod --replSet \"test\" &; mongo --eval \"rs.intiate({_id:'test',members:[{_id:0,host:'localhost:27017'}]})\""
```

Comment: I don't think that is the problem. I did docker run -d mongo /bin/bash -c "mongod --replSet \"test\"" IMMEDIATELY followed by docker exec PID /bin/bash -c "mongo --eval \"rs.initiate({_id:'test',members:[{_id:0,host:'localhost:27017'}]})\"". Everything worked fine. So I tried docker run -d mongo /bin/bash -c "mongod --replSet \"test\" & sleep 10 ; mongo --eval \"rs.initiate({_id:'test',members:[{_id:0,host:'localhost:27017'}]})\"" and I still get the same problem.

Comment: I half figured it out. 
docker run -d mongo /bin/bash -c "mongod --replSet \"test\" & sleep 10 ; mongo --eval \"rs.initiate({_id:'test',members:[{_id:0,host:'localhost:27017'}]})\" ; sleep 10000000000"
That works perfectly, except now the containers not "attached" (in that the container will exit when the mongod process dies) to the mongod process. Its just a dumb sleep for a long time. I don't know enough about linux to figure out how to attach it back to the mongod process.

Comment: Alright I figured that part out too. 

docker run -d mongo /bin/bash -c "mongod --replSet \"test\" & sleep 10 ; mongo --eval \"rs.initiate({_id:'test',members:[{_id:0,host:'localhost:27017'}]})\" ; wait $(pgrep mongod)"